# Phantomjs is duplicating content when exporting to PDF

Tags: pdf, phantomjs

I've encountered a weird issue with Phantomjs when converting an html file to pdf. My html, resulting pdf, and rasterize.js files are below:

- http://401web.com/_pub/2TRTI8E.html
- http://401web.com/_pub/2TRTI8E.pdf
- http://401web.com/_pub/rasterize.js

You will notice that in the PDF file, at page 6, the content gets cut off and then on page 7, the content is repeated and is then correct all the way to the end of the document.

The html file contains a series of  tags with their **src** attributes set as **data:image/png;base64...**

The application call to the phantom library is as follows:

```
phantomJS.Run("C:\path\to\directory\rasterize.js"),
                new[] { webpath, outFilePdf, "A4", "1", "portrait"}, null, null);
```

Note that sometimes the rendered pdf file will exhibit the break/repeat behavior in different locations within the document eg: page 7 instead of 6) but the same issue always occurs.

Also, I am using phantomjs throughout my application (with the same rasterize.js script) with no other issues. This only happens on this export and only if there are a number of images.

My theory is that there is something going on with the image.onload event, specifically with base64 data but I have no idea how to troubleshoot this.

This is all within a .Net MVC application. I am using the PhantomJS nuget package found here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PhantomJS/

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your version PhantomJS? Couldn't reproduce with v 2. By the way, what paper size do you use?

Comment: I am using v2.0.0. Worth noting that this is within a .Net MVC application (updated the question to reflect this). The paper size is A4 and zoom level is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: when running phantomjs locally via command line I was receiving the error below:

```
[CRITICAL] QNetworkReplyImpl: backend error: caching was enabled after some bytes had been written
libpng error: Read Error
```

I solved this (though I have no idea how/why) by replacing the cdn references in the html file to font-awesome.css and weather-icons.css files with locally hosted versions. After that, no more error and no more duplicate content.